# cake php habtm select does not set selected values

Tags: forms, cakephp, helper, has-and-belongs-to-many

Hello I have several troubles with HABTM and Form.
I am using CakePHP 2.3 and PHP 5.3.3

This is my code situation for the understanding of the scenario: Albums and Singles related with a HABTM relation. Albums cointains many Singles and Singles belongs to many Albums.

Model Album.php ( don't care about raisins: is my personal plugin for managing images )

```
App::uses('Raisin', 'Raisins.Model');
App::uses('PastryBehavior', 'Raisins.Model/Behavior');

class Album extends AppModel
{
public $name = 'Album';

public $actsAs = array(
    'Tags.Taggable',
    'Utils.Sluggable' => array(
        'label'     => 'title'
    ),
    'Raisins.Pastry',
    'SrEngine.Indexable',
    'SrEngine.HitCounter'
);

public $hasOne = array(
    'Image' => array('className' => 'Raisins.Raisin')
);

public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(

    'Single' 

);

public $belongsTo = array(
    'Users.User'
);
```

}

Controller AlbumsController.php ( edit part )

```
$this->request->data = $this->Album->read(null, $id);
$this->set('singles',$this->Album->Single->find('list'));
```

View

```
<?php echo $this->Form->input('Single',array('class' => 'span12','label' => 'Singoli' ) ); ?>
```

In the view I see the select populated from the values coming from the controller singles set, but the selected item, previously saved, is not highlighted.
Consider that in the database the habtm table contains the correct row populated with the data saved.
I read , somewehere in the middle, that some previous version of cake, prior to 2.3, used to have some problem related to habtm form select input.
I am very stuck at this because I have almost tried every known workaround without sorting any positive effect.
Any help, hint would be very appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Rudy

Comment: I have fixed my problem just upgrading the core of cakephp to 2.3.1 and it seems they have fixed the problem again.

Rudy